# Is it possible to iterate through a text file lines and use stringstream to parse each line?

Tags: c++, stringstream, sstream

What I am trying to do is read from a text file each line while parsing using sstream library. I got the program to run but it's stuck in a loop.

> Program:

```
string date;
int time;
float amount;

ifstream testFile("test.txt");
string token;
string line;

while(!testFile.eof()) {

    while(getline(testFile,token,',')){
        line += token + ' ';
    }
    stringstream ss(line); 
    ss >> date;
    ss >> time;
    ss >> amount;

    cout << "Date: " << date << " ";
    cout << "Time: " << time << " ";
    cout << "Amount: " << amount << " ";
    cout<<endl;

    ss.clear();

}    
testFile.close();
```

> test.txt:

```
10/12/1993,0800,7.97
11/12/1993,0800,8.97
```

> Wanted output:

```
Date: 10/12/1993 Time: 0800 Amount: 7.97
Date: 11/12/1993 Time: 0800 Amount: 8.97
```

How can I effectively produce this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't loop using `eof`. [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)
2. Read the file line by line. [Read file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line)
3. Split the string of each line using `,` as a seperator. [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)
4. Create `std::stringstream` objects of the second and third strings and use `operator>>` to obtain the `int` and `double` values from them.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    ifstream testFile("testdates.txt");    
    string line;

    while(getline(testFile, line)){

        string date;
        int time;
        float amount;

        std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ',', ' ');

        stringstream ss(line);

        ss >> date;
        ss >> time;
        ss >> amount;

        cout << "Date: " << date << " ";
        cout << "Time: " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << time << " ";
        cout << "Amount: " << amount << " ";

        cout << '\n';
    }   
}
```

You should read line by line using `getline`. You should check the return value of this to know when to quit (not `!eof`). Then you can replace all the commas with spaces and use your existing stream parse code to read the values.

Note the `ss.clear()` and `testFile.close()` are not required, as `ss` is recreated on each iteration and `testFile` is closed in its destructor.